# How to create a hint during defining the function which would indicates untypical object which returns?

Tags: python, function, syntax

i am trying to define function which would indicates that returns object type of
`hashlib.sha256(b'password')`
Explicitly what i wanna do is: `def encrypt(self, password: str) -> _hashlib.HASH:`
Unfortunately ,,_hashlib.HASH" cannot be read properly by my interpreter, there is an error of unknown object. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your module:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

It will [postpone evaluation of the annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations).

Further details in [*PEP 563 – Postponed Evaluation of Annotations*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) and, more recently, [*PEP 649 – Deferred Evaluation Of Annotations Using Descriptors*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0649/).